# how to get values from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, jquery-tokeninput

is it possible to compact all this id and name with variable?, I tried to  $('#vidyagames').tokenInput([variable]); also tried to input url but nothing worked. I have function, that gets all data, that should be instead of id and name but I replaced function name, variable nothing worked. Also tried to use jQuery("#vidyagames")  but also didnt work . I have database which consist table Game. And i want that instead of bunch of id and name was data from Game table and so i want without manually writing like this lines with id and name

```
 $scope.ingredient = [];


    $scope.getIngredient = function () {
        $http({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/ingredient',
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS");
                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.ingredient = response.data;

                },
                function (response) { // optional
                    console.log("ERROR");
                    console.log(response);
                });
    }
    $scope.getIngredient();
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#vidyagames').tokenInput([
      {id: 7, name: "Super Mario"},
      {id: 11, name: "Battletoads"},
      {id: 13, name: "Pong"},
      {id: 17, name: "The Legend of Zelda"},
      {id: 19, name: "Metroid"},
      {id: 23, name: "Donkey Kong Country"},
      {id: 29, name: "Super Smash Bros."},
      {id: 32, name: "Star Fox"},
      {id: 35, name: "Starcraft"},
      {id: 37, name: "Pokemon"},
      {id: 59, name: "Animal Crossing"},
      {id: 62, name: "Spyro the Dragon"},
      {id: 64, name: "Crash Bandicoot"},
      {id: 65, name: "Sonic the Hedgehog"},
      {id: 72, name: "Tomb Raider"},
      {id: 77, name: "Mortal Kombat"},
      {id: 81, name: "Space Invaders"}
    ], { 
      theme: "facebook",
      hintText: "Know of any cool games?",
      noResultsText: "Nothin' found.",
      searchingText: "Gaming...",
      preventDuplicates: true
  }); 

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Henny+Penny');

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
body {
  background: #e7e7e7 url('https://i.imgur.com/qoKmNN9.png'); /* https://subtlepatterns.com/natural-paper/ */
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #444;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
}

br { display: block; line-height: 1.6em; } 

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

input, textarea { 
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none; 
}

blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
strong,b { font-weight: bold; } 

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
img { border: 0; max-width: 100%; }

h1 { 
  font-family: 'Henny Penny', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 3.35em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #616161;
}

p { 
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* page structure */
#wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 35px 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#searchbar {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}


/* custom settings */
.token-input-token-facebook p { font-size: 1.0em; color: #555; }
.token-input-selected-token-facebook p { color: #fff; }


/** tokeninputs **/
/* Example tokeninput style #1: Token vertical list*/
ul.token-input-list {
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 1%;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    clear: left;
}

ul.token-input-list li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.token-input-list li input {
    border: 0;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-appearance: caret;
}

li.token-input-token {
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 1%;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    background-color: #d0efa0;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
}

li.token-input-token p {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li.token-input-token span {
    float: right;
    color: #777;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.token-input-selected-token {
    background-color: #08844e;
    color: #fff;
}

li.token-input-selected-token span {
    color: #bbb;
}

div.token-input-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.token-input-dropdown p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
}

div.token-input-dropdown ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.token-input-dropdown ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

div.token-input-dropdown ul li.token-input-dropdown-item {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

div.token-input-dropdown ul li.token-input-dropdown-item2 {
    background-color: #fff;
}

div.token-input-dropdown ul li em {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

div.token-input-dropdown ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item {
    background-color: #d0efa0;
}




/** tokeninputs facebook **/
/* Example tokeninput style #2: Facebook style */
ul.token-input-list-facebook {
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 1%;
    width: 550px;
    border: 1px solid #8496ba;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    min-height: 1px;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    clear: left;
}

ul.token-input-list-facebook li input {
    border: 0;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 2px 0;
    -webkit-appearance: caret;
}

li.token-input-token-facebook {
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 15px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    background-color: #eff2f7;
    color: #000;
    cursor: default;
    border: 1px solid #ccd5e4;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li.token-input-token-facebook p {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li.token-input-token-facebook span {
    color: #a6b3cf;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.token-input-selected-token-facebook {
    background-color: #5670a6;
    border: 1px solid #3b5998;
    color: #fff;
}

li.token-input-input-token-facebook {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-facebook {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-facebook p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li.token-input-dropdown-item-facebook {
    background-color: #fff;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li.token-input-dropdown-item2-facebook {
    background-color: #fff;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li em {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-facebook {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Dynamic Tag Input Suggestions</h1>
    <p>Start typing the name of a popular video game to get some helpful suggestions.</p>

    <div id="searchbar">
      <input type="text" id="vidyagames" name="vidya">
    </div>
  </div><!-- @end #wrapper -->
</body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/src/jquery.tokeninput.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the question? If you're asking how to minify the array of objects in the `tokenInput()` call, then there's not much you can do other than remove spaces and line returns.

Comment: I wanna replace those id and name with variable, that get data from response

Comment: I assume by response you mean an AJAX request, if so it should just be `$('#vidyagames').tokenInput(data, { theme: "facebook", /* other settings... */ });`, where `data` is the response from your AJAX request

Comment: I tried it but didn't work also tried putting url

Comment: Can you show the attempt you made at making the AJAX request so we can help you debug it

Comment: I added $scope.ingredient instead of data

Comment: `$scope`? Sounds like AngularJS... You may want to [edit] your question to include that tag.

Comment: I got variable that consists what i need but idk how to replace those with id and name in that one. i did $('#vidyagames').tokenInput(data, { theme: "facebook", /* other settings... */ }); but it doesn't work

Comment: Please post a snippet of what's your expected result, as well as more info in your question: it isn't clear from it what you are trying to achieve. Also please use the correct tags (`jquery` and possibly `angular` as it looks like that's what you're using here).

Answer (score 0):

I entered data instead of bunch id and name there. Also added tokenValue:name. It previously didnt work bcz tokenValue:"name" name was double quoted